# Ember.js - Setting a model and routing dynamically via API data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I'm working on building a dynamic model for a project that reacts to data sent from an API. The api will return, among other things, what your location should be and this in turn becomes the url. So, eg:

```
 {
  location: 'xyz'
  (...)
 }
```

So currently my router will transition to the right route dynamically. But I still have to hardcode each route ( `IndexRoute`, `LocationXYZRoute`, `LocationABCRoute`, etc).

My goal is to create a single route that handles things dynamically. We'll call it `App.LocationRoute` and my routes would look something like:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
 this.resource(':location', function() {
   this.route(':subLocation')
  }
}
```

Now, I have two architectural questions:

1) Whats a good way to handle this sort of dynamic routing? (I've read through the guide about dynamic routing using the `':post_id'` type example, but I think I need a more holistic example to really grasp it.

2) The API sends back a whole host of other data as well. I want to add this to the route's model but I also have some other static models. Doing...

`this.controllerFor(location).set('content', APIdata);`

... works, but it does not set for routes currently using static models. I tried something like:

`this.controllerFor(location).set('apiData', APIdata);`

and...

`this.controllerFor(location).set('model:apiData', APIdata);`

... but neither worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you should use dynamic segment

```
this.resource('location', { path: '/location/:location_id' }, function() {
    this.resource('sublocation', { path: '/sublocation/:location_id' });
});
```

2) Are you using ember-data? You could check sideloaded data. Anyway, you could read the json and set the payload of each entity for each specific route.

```
this.controllerFor('location').set('content', APIdata.location);
this.controllerFor('user').set('content', APIdata.user);
```

People could help you better, if you separate your questions and create a http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ with isolated each specific case?